# newly rebuilt openstack compute host is not starting iscsid on boot

Tags: openstack

I have a number of compute nodes that are working just fine, I rebuilt several (changing the location of their iSCSI root disks)  now they no longer start up iscsid on boot

What starts the iscsid service???
it is not enabled in systemd on any of the systems and while I can set it to start in systemd on the new systems, I would prefer to figure out why it is not getting started and fix that issue, so my systems are configured consistently

base os is RHEL 7.9 x86_64
cinder package is openstack-cinder-15.4.0-1.el7.noarch

FWIW: the openstack installation was performed using the same shell script for all the systems
thanks

Comment: How do you address your disks, e.g. `/dev/disk-by/...`? `udev` could change it's order of naming the devices which could mess up your iscsi configuration.

Comment: it doesn't appear to be a udev issue, but if I reboot the system a second time after the install, the services are started?!?

Comment: I don't know how the installer of RHEL works, I use openSUSE or SLES mainly, and those reboot automatically after the initial installation. Then they run through YaST stage 2 which does some post-install magic and afterwards a `systemctl isolate` is executed to start the `multi-user.target`. So in your case, does one reboot solve it? If you reboot the machine multiple times, do the services all come up? Has this behavior changed and that's why you're asking?